# Passing the value that is received from the callback state as preselected in the Dropdown in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am passing the state from the Component A to B when I am redirected from A to B via the link. The state in Component A has some values that will populate the dropdown box in the Component B.

Component A:

```
    const state = useLocation().state
    
    <Link to={goToPage(buttonProps.metadata.key)} state={{ callbackState: activeState }}>
```

Component B:

```js
const [selectedHeader, setSelectedHeader] = useState("");
const handleHeaderChange = (event) => {
  setSelectedHeader(event.target.value);
};

<FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: "100%", maxWidth: 180, mt: 1 }}>
  <Select
    style={{ height: "30px" }}
    value={selectedHeader}
    onChange={handleHeaderChange}
  >
    {state.callbackState.dataset.header.map((header) => (
      <MenuItem key={header.value} value={header.value}>
        {header.value}-{header.meta.tooltiptext}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>;
```

I am getting all the values in the dropdown. However, I need my dropdown to be preselected with the specific value that is passed via the state like this:

```
                        <div className="label">
                            <p>{state.callbackState.dataset.label}</p>
                        </div>
```

It works in above scenario where a text from callback is rendered in the div but in the case of the dropdown box it is not working as it is not getting preselected with the value from the state.
In my case, I want the dropdown box in component B to have preselected value from {header.value}.

Thank you for your time.